# How to change button name in primefaces calendar

Tags: css, primefaces, calendar

I am using the below code to display only time.

This code displays two buttons called "Current Date" and "Close". My requirement is to choose only time, not date. So I have to change this as "Current Time". How to do this? Can someone help me please.

I am using primefaces 5.1.

Also the change shouldn't affect the other calendar which requires date as well.

Comment: code snippet:

<p:calendar id="id1" showButtonPanel="true" readonlyInput="true" value="#{view.startTime}" pattern="HH:mm:ss" timeOnly="true" navigator="true" mode="popup" >

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with the below code.

```
<p:calendar id="id1" showButtonPanel="true" readonlyInput="true" value="#{view.startTime}" pattern="HH:mm:ss" timeOnly="true" navigator="true" mode="popup" locale="en"/>

<script type="text/javascript">    
        PrimeFaces.locales ['en'] = {
                closeText: 'Close',
                currentText: 'Current Time'
        };
</script>
```